# No funciona DataBinding en un textbox C# winform

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Solicito su amable colaboración con lo siguiente, tengo una clase alumno y un formulario con 2 textbox, en el evento load del formulario declaro la propiedad DataBindings de cada textbox con los atributos de la clase, sin embargo cuando seteo un atributo de la clase, no se actualiza el valor en el objeto textbox o viseversa.

```js
public class alumno : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

private string _nombre;
private string _apellido;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public string Nombre { get {return _nombre;} set { _nombre=value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}

public string Apellido { get {return _apellido;} set { _apellido=value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        } 

}

 private void FrmPptoIndRed_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

txtNombre.DataBindings.Add("Text", _alumno, "Nombre");
txtApellido.DataBindings.Add("Text", _alumno, "Apellido");

_alumno.Nombre = "Pedro"; //no actualiza el textbox
txtApellido.Text = "Picapiedra"; //no actualiza el atributo de la clase _alumno.Apellido

}
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal o que falta. Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Fijate que errores salen en la consola, los errores de binding se muestran ahi.

Answer (score 1):

Se debe a que tu metodo de enlace de datos esta por default en validacion del control, agrega el siguiente codigo para que la actualizacion sea cada vez que la propiead ligada se modifique:

```
txtNombre.DataBindings.Add("Text", _alumno, "Nombre");
txtNombre.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
txtApellido.DataBindings.Add("Text", _alumno, "Apellido");
txtApellido.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
```

[Documentacion de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Anexo:

Probando el codigo funciona correctamente de mi lado esta es la forma en la que lo maneje debido a que no tengo acceso a c# 6.0 en la maquina que estoy en este momento:

```
public class alumno : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _nombre;
    private string _apellido;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Nombre
    {
        get { return _nombre; }
        set
        {
            _nombre = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Apellido
    {
        get { return _apellido; }
        set
        {
            _apellido = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }        

}
```

En el evento load del formulario:

```
 private void FrmPptoIndRed_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _alumno = new alumno(); //instanciamos la clase de alumno
     _alumno.Nombre = "Pedro"; //no actualiza el textbox
     _alumno.Apellido = "Picapiedra";
     //textBox2.Text = "Picapiedra"; //no hay razon para hacer esto, usas la propiedad _alumno.Apellido
      textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", _alumno, "Apellido");
      textBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _alumno, "Nombre");
    textBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Lo añadí de la siguiente manera y aun así no funciona   txtNombre.DataBindings.Add("Text", _alumno, "Nombre",false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
txtApellido.DataBindings.Add("Text", _alumno, "Apellido",false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

Comment: Esta es la unica linea de codigo que no deberia funcionar `txtApellido.Text = "Picapiedra";` debido a que la propiedad es la que controla el binding, el resto debe verse reflejado al momento de que las propiedades son actualizadas o cunado el usuario entra un valor en el control, pudieras ser mas especifico que es lo que no funciona o que marca tu depuracion, pues veo que haces uso de c# 6.0